# How to create a edit profile page for users?

Tags: profiles

How do I create an Edit Profile page for users on the frontend with custom fields using Wordpress?

**Example Fields:**

Image Upload Field

Text Field

Etc...

And how can a user can save these fields?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use profile builder plugin for it. here is shortcode for frontend edit profile `[wppb-edit-profile]` https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/

Comment: Thanks . I want to do this without the plugin and personalization

Comment: ok you can get some idea form here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312839/how-to-create-a-edit-profile-page-for-users-on-frontend-with-custom-fields-on-wo

Comment: Apart from me i'm using a front-ent edit profile plugin for front ent user edit porile form https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-edit-profile/

Comment: For anyone looking, this plugin is no longer available for download since October 2019. It's taken down because of a guideline violation so the developer might update it in the future.

Comment: I've migrated several answers to comments as they weren't answers, they were actually product recommendations. Answers need to be self contained, and recommendations are off topic here

Answer (score 6):

This is a pretty big thing to ask but basically you go:

Add extra user fields using the code from this answer: [Extra User Fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214723/52240)

Change them with a custom template for the user:

```php
/* Get user info. */
global $current_user, $wp_roles;
get_currentuserinfo();
```

Now you have the logged in user data which you can then alter.
Create fields for the user to change and fill them with the current info
e.g.

```php
<input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'first_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
```

Then save your data:  First check if empty and then overwrite the data.

```
 if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
```

Then redirect the user if saved:

```
 /* Redirect so the page will show updated info.*/
if ( count( $error ) == 0 ) {
    //action hook for plugins and extra fields saving
    do_action('edit_user_profile_update', $current_user->ID);
    $location = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'user_location', true );
    wp_safe_redirect( get_bloginfo('url') . str_replace( ' ','-', $location ) );
    exit;
}
```

It works this way. I did it in the exact same way.

Comment: Thanks . Are these changes on the admin panel ?

Comment: @Interactive - could you explain the redirect with showing updated info a little more? I've got this working except after form submit the page shows the old info in the form fields. If I refresh the page then the new info shows. The user is being updated when I check on the admin side. Thanks!

Comment: I left several security fixes and  clarified the linked code was a WPSE answer not a plugin recommendation.