# If I am not writing a theme, how do I add custom fields to a user for a plugin

Tags: plugins, custom-field

I have read [this stack article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214719/how-do-i-add-a-field-on-the-users-profile-for-example-country-age-etc), but it refers to themes.

I am writing a plugin not a theme. Do I basically do the same in the plugin's activation method? I have been reading the developer documents, but they don't seem to cover where things like this should be done. Just that they *can* be done.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Actually, the question you refer to is about plugins.So you should be fine following that approach.

Comment: Thanks cjbj. I'll do that so. Seems like a straight forward approach. But I am trying very hard to adhere to best practice as this is a project someone else may take over.

Comment: Actually, things like this should always be done in a plugin. Themes are about representation of the content, plugins about adding functionality

Answer (score 0):

> I have read [this stack article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214719/how-do-i-add-a-field-on-the-users-profile-for-example-country-age-etc), but it refers to themes.

<strike>It does not. The word "theme" is mentioned nowhere in the question or answers.</strike> Edit: Apparently it mentions functions.php. Regardless, the below still applies.

> Do I basically do the same in the plugin's activation method?

You do not need to (and should not) use the activation method of the plugin. The code from the answer can go anywhere in a plugin *or* theme.

Developing themes and plugins is essentially the same process, with the same code. The only differences are:

- WordPress will only automatically load template files from themes.
- Plugins are loaded/run before the theme.
- You need to use different functions to get the path or URL of plugins (eg. `plugins_url()`) to those used for themes (eg. `get_theme_file_uri()`).
- Functions that should only run once when the plugin or theme is activated are hooked differently.

Plus the philosophical difference that themes should be responsible for *presentation*, and everything else belongs in a plugin.

Any code you see for doing something in WordPress will work the same ina  theme or plugin unless any of the above points are relevant.

Comment: "It does not."

Both of the links the article sources refer to a functions.php file in the theme.

Comment: And saying "It should not use the activation method" but "can go anywhere in a plugin or theme" is incongruous.

If it should not go in the activation method; where *should* it go?

Comment: Literally anywhere else. Maybe you should start wondering if you're already up to writing a plugin if this is the question you need to ask. I'd advice by diving into WordPress hooks (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks) first.

Plugin code is literally run as soon as the plugin runs. So if you're code needs to be run whenever then place it simply in the plugin file. If not, add the code to the correct hook to ensure the code runs at the correct time

Comment: I have read it. It tells you how to do it. Not where it should be done.

Comment: @JeffreyvonGrumbkow, "you should start wondering if you're already up to writing a plugin" I am sure you could have figured a nicer way to say this, or just not say that at all as it doesn't add any value to your comment.

Comment: @Wing A plugin's a PHP file. The code goes in the PHP file. That's it.

Comment: @wing, the difference between plugins and themes is the "entry point". While with themes it is always in the `functions.php` file, in plugins it is the file that contains the plugin's header. For most non trivial plugins and themes you will have more than one php file, with the other files being included by the "entry point" file. It does not matter in which of the included files you place a code as long as it is being included.

Comment: @JeffreyvonGrumbkow I have read the document on hooks. I know what a hook is and how to use it. I was asking a best practice question. True, I could have specified that this is a large project encompassing a complex domain-specific problem which is going to end up needing multiple classes modelling multiple behaviours. But I thought this was a fairly simple question that would involve a simple answer. Not *wrong* information about what the previous article I had already read says and doesn't say and a request to provide my PHP programming credentials. Way to make this incredibly hostile.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Thanks. I've looked at the load behaviour of the WPBB class structure, it wasn't immediately clear there.

Comment: @wing WPBB? anyway, structure is up to you, there are all kind of boilerplates to use for themes and plugins, but you do not have to follow them (I do not).

Comment: You're the one feeling attacked. I want being hostile at all. There isn't really a best practice as you set up plugins any way you like and any way can be best practice based on the needs. If you want yoi can make a plugin fully MVC or create a singleton class. Whatever you want really