# WP author meta disappeared

Tags: user-meta

My WP site has stopped displaying user meta data. For example, the biographical info has disappeared from both the front- and back-end. I've found it is still present in the underlying database: any ideas how I can get it populating the back-end again at least?

Comment: add the [classic editor plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/) because the 5.0 gutenberg editor update is messing with your post_meta **maybe?**

Comment: Appreciate the idea - turns out site's still using 4.8.7... (Not actually my own site, before people start to judge!)

Comment: Was there a plugin installed that was being used to manage the meta_data? ACF, or CMB maybe? If you know the keys (the names of the meta) you can "re-add" it with [this technique](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214719/how-do-i-add-a-field-on-the-users-profile-for-example-country-age-etc). It sounds like the theme or plugin which was previously adding the author-meta was removed. You'll want to "re-add" it with keys that match the keys previously used & everything should click into place.