# How to add required fields in user profile admin page?

Tags: forms, profiles

I managed to add custom fields in the user profile admin page like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214719/how-do-i-add-a-field-on-the-users-profile-for-example-country-age-etc).

The problem is when I add `required="true"` or `required="required"` on fields, the submit button do action without checking required empty inputs.

The submit is running by Ajax ?

How can I force to make required fields in this admin page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in `profile.php`, `edit-user.php` and `new-user.php`, you have to :

1. add `form-required` class on `<tr>`, not on the input field
2. add `aria-required="true"` on the input field